# Filterable portfolio in WordPress using jQuery isotope

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery

I want to filter portfolio using Isotope. I can show the items but can't filter. Here is my code. Have a look and share your thoughts what i am missing.

```
 <ul id="cat">
        <li>
            <ol class="type">
                <?php
                    $terms = get_terms('portfolio-type');
                    $count = count($terms);
                        echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>';
                    if ( $count > 0 ){

                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                            $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                            $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                            echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-filter=".'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>


 <div class="portfolio-items">  

    <?php 

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 8 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 web">    
      <div class="portfolio-item">

        <div class="hover-bg"> 
            <a href="<?php display_taxonomy_terms('portfolio-link'); ?>" title="Project description" rel="prettyPhoto" target="_blank">
            <div class="hover-text">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <small><?php display_taxonomy_terms('portfolio-type'); ?></small> 
            </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Project Image" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/> </a>          
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;

    ?>


  </div>

<script>
(function($){

var $container = $('.portfolio-item');

// create a clone that will be used for measuring container width
$containerProxy = $container.clone().empty().css({ visibility: 'hidden' });   

$container.after( $containerProxy );  

// get the first item to use for measuring columnWidth
var $item = $container.find('.hover-bg').eq(0);

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $(window).smartresize( function() {

        // calculate columnWidth
        var colWidth = Math.floor( $containerProxy.width() / 2 ); // Change this number to your desired amount of columns

        // set width of container based on columnWidth
        $container.css({
            width: colWidth * 2 // Change this number to your desired amount of columns
        })
        .isotope({

            // disable automatic resizing when window is resized
            resizable: false,

            // set columnWidth option for masonry
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: colWidth
            }
        });

    // trigger smartresize for first time
    }).smartresize();
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#cat a').click(function(){

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector, animationEngine : "css" });
    $('#cat a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;

   });

  } ) ( jQuery );
  </script>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're running into? Are there any JavaScript errors in your Browser Tools Console? Have you enabled PHP Debugging and are there any PHP errors? What is the expected output and expected result?

Comment: PHP codes are just fine. It shows the portfolio items as it's post types. Only problem is jQuery is not triggering properly. That's why when i click on the filter "terms" i.e. "web design" "App developemnt" etc, then no filtering, just blank. Please be noted, by default "all" is only showing the available items.